# Multiple text format in a RichTextBox

Tags: c#, richtextbox

Suppose there are two lines. A red line. A blue line.
Who can help with.

Comment: I think you'd have to show some more effort before anyone is willing to help you. You didn't even state your problem.

Comment: I agree with @Felix, anyway I want to help you because you're new here. Remember to try to write your code before asking here, show your efforts and write a clear and detailed question. Welcome to SO.

Comment: I get this strange feeling that there are some deep philosophical implications behind this question.  Or maybe just Dr. Seuss.

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
void AppendText(RichTextBox box, Color color, string text)
{
    int start = box.TextLength;
    box.AppendText(text);
    int end = box.TextLength;

    // Textbox may transform chars, so (end-start) != text.Length
    box.Select(start, end - start + 1);
    box.SelectionColor = color;
    // could set box.SelectionBackColor, box.SelectionFont, etc...
    box.SelectionLength = 0; // clear
}
```

and then

```
AppendText(rtb, Color.Red, "line1");
AppendText(rtb, Color.Blue, "line2");
```

Comment: I have done it. Thank you very much. The correct answer to my question that then.